# HP P2000 MSA G3 SAN-SNMP Trap Setup

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage-area-network, snmp

I'm trying to setup an SNMP trap for an HP P2000 G3 MSA SAN to report on the overall disk performance parameters (mostly I/O rates). We have a server monitor suite running which can use SNMP traps to trigger alerts to be sent to specific emails.

My problem is that I cannot find the specific SNMP walk which will allow me to do this. Both my boss and I tried separately and came to the same result. We found a package of MIB files which seemed to be for our SAN, but when imported into our server monitor it didn't seem to contain the correct OIDs.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this, and, if so, which parameter you configured?

If this is not possible with this SAN, is there a separate way to do this? Free is preferable.

As I am very new to SNMP, please excuse any misuse of terms or any misunderstanding of the protocol this post may contain. I'm still learning. In any case, I do appreciate any and all help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pull SNMP performance stats out of the HP P2000 G3 SAN. It's a limitation.

There's a [Windows host-based metrics tool available](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4304839&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_5e878f833e2c4d078c0e8368bd%257CswEnvOID%253D%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), but you're best off measuring from the consumers of the SAN data. I do believe SNMP traps can be sent for hardware alerts/failures. That configuration is straightforward from the MSA interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it that a shot. Too bad we can't pull the performance stats. In any case, thank you for the help.